# Conversion of data in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following type of data assigned to var `dataTransformation`, which I'm taking from the user in apache superset using metric.

```
{country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 91.779}
{country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 91.492}
{country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 91.195}
{country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 94.865}
{country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 94.722}
{country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 94.502}
{country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1960, value: 30.939}
{country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1961, value: 30.332}
{country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1962, value: 29.506}
```

But I want to convert it into the below format. I tried it using the array map function, loops, and string concatenation but it is not efficient. Is there any way to do it in javascript?

```
{
   "South Asia": [
      ["Afghanistan", 91.779, 91.492, 91.195],
      ["Bangladesh", 94.865, 94.722, 94.502],
   ],
   "North America":[
      ["Canada", 30.939, 30.332, 29.506],
    ],
}
```

I'm expecting a guide on how to do it, not fully working code.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two formats? What is the `value` in the first format and what is the three numbers in the second format?

Comment: I want to map all countries to the same regions like Afghanistan and Bangladesh to South Asia with its year-wise value in a respective array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
    const data = [
      { country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 91.779 },
      { country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 91.492 },
      { country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 91.195 },
      { country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 94.865 },
      { country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 94.722 },
      { country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 94.502 },
      { country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1960, value: 30.939 },
      { country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1961, value: 30.332 },
      { country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1962, value: 29.506 },
    ];


    const transformation = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const { country, region, year, value } = curr;
      if (!acc[region]) {
        acc[region] = [];
        acc[region].push([country, value]);
        return acc;
      }

      let isCountryExist = false;

      acc[region].forEach((el) => {
        if (el.includes(country)) {
          isCountryExist = true;
          el.push(value);
        }
      });
      if (!isCountryExist) {
        acc[region].push([country, value]);
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});

    console.log(transformation);
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
const data = [{
  country: "Afghanistan",
  region: "South Asia",
  year: 1960,
  value: 91.779
},{
  country: "Afghanistan",
  region: "South Asia",
  year: 1961,
  value: 91.492
},{
  country: "Afghanistan",
  region: "South Asia",
  year: 1962,
  value: 91.195
},{
  country: "Bangladesh",
  region: "South Asia",
  year: 1960,
  value: 94.865
},{
  country: "Bangladesh",
  region: "South Asia",
  year: 1961,
  value: 94.722
},{
  country: "Bangladesh",
  region: "South Asia",
  year: 1962,
  value: 94.502
},{
  country: "Canada",
  region: "North America",
  year: 1960,
  value: 30.939
},{
  country: "Canada",
  region: "North America",
  year: 1961,
  value: 30.332
},{
  country: "Canada",
  region: "North America",
  year: 1962,
  value: 29.506
}];

const res = data.reduce((acc, {country, region, year, value}) => {
  acc = {
    ...acc,
    [region]: {
      ...acc[region],
      [country]: !acc?.[region]?.[country] ? [value] : acc[region][country].concat(value) 
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, { });

console.log(res);
```

Comment: `region` should be an array according to the question. But you mistakenly put in an object.

Comment: @DeC I know that. but I thought my format is better to use than Asker's format. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dataTransformation` is an `Array`, the first step should be converting it to an object of regions containing objects with the countries as keys and arrays as values. This would keep the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of this task at the minimum:

```js
const dataTransformation = [
  {country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 91.779},
  {country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 91.492},
  {country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 91.195},
  {country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 94.865},
  {country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 94.722},
  {country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 94.502},
  {country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1960, value: 30.939},
  {country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1961, value: 30.332},
  {country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1962, value: 29.506}
];

const dataTransformationObject = dataTransformation.reduce((o, i) => {
  o[i.region] = o[i.region] || {};
  o[i.region][i.country] = o[i.region][i.country] || [];
  o[i.region][i.country].push(i.value);
  return o;
},{});

console.log(dataTransformationObject);
```

The previous code will return this object:

```json
{
  "South Asia": {
    "Afghanistan": [
      91.779,
      91.492,
      91.195
    ],
    "Bangladesh": [
      94.865,
      94.722,
      94.502
    ]
  },
  "North America": {
    "Canada": [
      30.939,
      30.332,
      29.506
    ]
  }
}
```

And I strongly recommend you to use it directly in this way. Why? because to access to `data > region > country`, you can do it directly: e.g, `data['North America']['Canada'][0]` is `30.939`. Otherwise you would need to iterate in the array of regions to find a country, and that would not be optimal.

But if you still need the output that you requested in your answer, you can transform the previous object to achieve it:

```js
const dataTransformation = [
  {country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 91.779},
  {country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 91.492},
  {country: "Afghanistan", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 91.195},
  {country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1960, value: 94.865},
  {country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1961, value: 94.722},
  {country: "Bangladesh", region: "South Asia", year: 1962, value: 94.502},
  {country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1960, value: 30.939},
  {country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1961, value: 30.332},
  {country: "Canada", region: "North America", year: 1962, value: 29.506}
];

const dataTransformationObject = dataTransformation.reduce((o, i) => {
  o[i.region] = o[i.region] || {};
  o[i.region][i.country] = o[i.region][i.country] || [];
  o[i.region][i.country].push(i.value);
  return o;
},{});

const final = Object.entries(dataTransformationObject).reduce((o, e) => {
  o[e[0]] = Object.keys(e[1]).map((c) => [c, ...e[1][c]]);
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(final);
```

Which will give you the desired output:

```json
{
  "South Asia": [
    [
      "Afghanistan",
      91.779,
      91.492,
      91.195
    ],
    [
      "Bangladesh",
      94.865,
      94.722,
      94.502
    ]
  ],
  "North America": [
    [
      "Canada",
      30.939,
      30.332,
      29.506
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation.. but project requirement was second solution.

Comment: Learned something with your first answer. Thanks for sharing 